# Replace character only on specific occurrence

Tags: python

I have some tab-separated values in a list looking something like this:

```
A    B    C|D    E    F|G|H|I    J|K|L    M    N
1    2    3|4    5    6|7|8|9    1|2|3    4    5
```

I want to replace the first occurrence of "|" in the 5th column so that the output becomes

```
A    B    C|D    E    F    G|H|I    J|K|L    M    N
1    2    3|4    5    6    7|8|9    1|2|3    4    5
```

Is there anyway I can use replace, like line.replace("|", "\t", 1), but making it only do this on a specific column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way:

```
line = 'A\tB\tC|D\tE\tF|G|H|I\tJ|K|L\tM\tN'
columns = line.split('\t')
columns[4] = columns[4].replace("|", "\t", 1)
new_line = '\t'.join(columns)
print(new_line) # Output: A B   C|D E   F   G|H|I   J|K|L   M   N
```